# How to loop through json nested objects in react js

Tags: reactjs, json

SomeOne please help me. I am spending too long trying to display some data
I wish to iterate over a nested object json response using react js and access ["1. open"] after the date.
[The image of json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N7Xs.png)

the json data is
{
"Meta Data": {
"1. Information": "Weekly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
"2. Symbol": "IBM",
"3. Last Refreshed": "2022-06-08",
"4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Weekly Time Series": {
"2022-06-08": {
"1. open": "142.9800",
"2. high": "144.7300",
"3. low": "140.1500",
"4. close": "140.8300",
"5. volume": "10659817"
},

render() {
console.log(this.state.users);

```
   return (
     // div>{this.state.users["Meta Data"]["2. Symbol"]}</div>
     <div> {Object.keys(this.state.users).map((item, i) => (
         <div key={i}> {this.state.users[item]["2022-06-08"]} 
              {Object.keys(["2022-06-08"]).map((c, i) => (
                <li key={i}>{["2022-06-08"][c]["1. open"]}</li>
              ))}
         </div>
          


       ))}


    </div> 
   );
```

But the error shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDyi0.png)

Comment: Can you please paste out your JSON here in the question instead of image? That will help to answer it.

Comment: {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Weekly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2022-06-08",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Weekly Time Series": {
        "2022-06-08": {
            "1. open": "142.9800",
            "2. high": "144.7300",
            "3. low": "140.1500",
            "4. close": "140.8300",
            "5. volume": "10659817"
        },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you. Please refer to the demo too I made for you.

**Stackblitz Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7zuxq4?file=index.tsx,App.tsx

```
 <div>
      {Object.keys(weeklyTimeSeries).map((key) => (
        <ul>
          <b>{key}</b>

          {Object.keys(weeklyTimeSeries[key]).map((ckey) => (
            <li>
              {ckey} = {weeklyTimeSeries[key][ckey]}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ))}
 </div>
```

**Note:** I have made a general demo.  So you have to map through your state variable instead of mine.

Comment: Hello Thank you for helping me. But I am getting error Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {1. open, 2. high, 3. low, 4. close, 5. volume}).

Comment: I think it is because the map is not able to get the innermost data of 1.open object

Comment: the api data is from this website: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo

Comment: I think you just need to make one check over this code. So once your data available then only perform this operation.

Comment: {Object.keys(this.state.users).map((key) => (
                       <ul>
                           <b>{key= "Weekly Time Series"}</b>
                           {Object.keys(this.state.users[key]).map((ckey) => (
                               <li>
                                   {ckey}
                               </li>
                           ))}
                           
                       </ul>
                   ))}    I got one output

Comment: Weekly Time Series
2022-06-08
2022-06-03
2022-05-27
2022-05-20
2022-05-13
2022-05-06
2022-04-29
2022-04-22
2022-04-14
2022-04-08
2022-04-01
2022-03-25
2022-03-18
2022-03-11
2022-03-04
2022-02-25
2022-02-18
2022-02-11
2022-02-04
2022-01-28  My output showed the date. But even if i modify I am not able to get the [1. open] value

Comment: Thank you so much I was able to get the answer with a small edit.

Comment: Glad to know this.  Can you please let me know what was that edit you made?

Answer (score 0):

use recursive approach to loop through the json object you will get it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973017/iterate-through-nested-json-in-react-js  refer this answer

Comment: I am not able to recursively loop through. I am creating syntax error i believe. And the link is converting object into arrays but the data I have is pretty long for object to arrray manual conversion

Comment: Add the json data sample if possible

Comment: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo the data is from this website

Comment: I hope you found the solution on previous answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).